# Excel VBA Weighted Average If Custom Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to write a custom function that will check 2 criteria in a range then do a weighted average of any matches it finds. My code is below and it is not interpreting my criteria correctly. It's displaying a #Value on my Criteria. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :D

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6aefGNRPaHiRlR4a3Vvc3RNamM/edit?usp=sharing

```
Function WeightedAverageIf(Range As Range, Citeria1 As String, Column1 As Integer, Criteria2 As String, Column2 As Integer, Column3 As Integer, Column4 As Integer)
     lr = Range.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Dim num1 As Integer, per1 As Integer, num2 As Integer, per2 As Integer, counter As Integer
     coutner = 0
     For x = 1 To lr
        If counter = 0 Then
           If Range.Cells(x, Column1) = Criteria1 And Range.Cells(x, Column2) = Criteria2 Then num1 = Cells(x, Column3) And per1 = Range.Cells(x, Column4) And counter = counter + 1
           End If
        If counter > 0 Then
           If Range.Cells(x, Column1) = Criteria1 And Cells(x, Column2) = Criteria2 Then num2 = Range.Cells(x, Column3) And per2 = Range.Cells(x, Column4) And counter = counter + 1
           per1 = (((per1 * num1) + (per2 * num2)) / (num1 + num2))
           num1 = (num1 + num2)
        End If
     Next x
     WeightedAverageIf = per1
End Function
```

Comment: This isn't going to solve your problem, but you shouldn't use Range as the variable name for your Range, since Range is a key VBA word.  So it'll confuse VBA if you use Range when you really mean Range...see what I mean?  Change it to R or Rng or something other than Range to help make your code a bit easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you both for your help you pointed me in the right direction! I had to add some checks and move around the if statement but I have a final product that should work for anyone so I decided to post the finished code.

Here is the code with just one match criteria.

```
Function WeightedAverageIf(Rng As Range, Find1 As String, Find1Column As Integer, WeightColumn As Integer, AVGColumn As Integer)
    lr = Rng.Rows.Count
    Dim num1 As Double, per1 As Double, num2 As Double, per2 As Double, counter As Integer
    coutner = 0

    For x = 1 To lr

        If counter > 0 Then
            If Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn) = 0 Or Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn) = "" Or IsNumeric(Rng.Cells(x, AVGColumn)) = False Or IsNumeric(Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn)) = False Then GoTo skipif
            If Rng.Cells(x, Find1Column) = Find1 Then
                num2 = Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn)
                per2 = Rng.Cells(x, AVGColumn)
                counter = counter + 1
            End If

            per1 = (((per1 * num1) + (per2 * num2)) / (num1 + num2))
            num1 = (num1 + num2)
        End If

        If counter = 0 Then
            If Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn) = 0 Or Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn) = "" Or IsNumeric(Rng.Cells(x, AVGColumn)) = False Or IsNumeric(Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn)) = False Then GoTo skipif
            If Rng.Cells(x, Find1Column) = Find1 Then
                num1 = Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn)
                per1 = Rng.Cells(x, AVGColumn)
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        End If
skipif:
    Next x
    If counter = 1 Then
    WeightedAverageIf = per1
    ElseIf counter = 0 Then
    WeightedAverageIf = 0
    Else
    WeightedAverageIf = per1
    End If
End Function
```

And here is the code with 2 match criteria.

```
Function WeightedAverageIfs(Rng As Range, Find1 As String, Find1Column As Integer, Find2 As String, FindColumn2 As Integer, WeightColumn As Integer, AVGColumn As Integer)
    lr = Rng.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim num1 As Double, per1 As Double, num2 As Double, per2 As Double, counter As Integer
    coutner = 0

    For x = 1 To lr

        If counter > 0 Then
            If Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn) = 0 Or Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn) = "" Or IsNumeric(Rng.Cells(x, AVGColumn)) = False Or IsNumeric(Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn)) = False Then GoTo skipif
            If Rng.Cells(x, Find1Column) = Find1 And Rng.Cells(x, FindColumn2) = Find2 Then
                num2 = Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn)
                per2 = Rng.Cells(x, AVGColumn)
                counter = counter + 1
            End If

            per1 = (((per1 * num1) + (per2 * num2)) / (num1 + num2))
            num1 = (num1 + num2)
        End If

        If counter = 0 Then
            If Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn) = 0 Or Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn) = "" Or IsNumeric(Rng.Cells(x, AVGColumn)) = False Or IsNumeric(Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn)) = False Then GoTo skipif
            If Rng.Cells(x, Find1Column) = Find1 And Rng.Cells(x, FindColumn2) = Find2 Then
                num1 = Rng.Cells(x, WeightColumn)
                per1 = Rng.Cells(x, AVGColumn)
                counter = counter + 1
            End If
        End If
skipif:
    Next x
    If counter = 1 Then
    WeightedAverageIfs = per1
    ElseIf counter = 0 Then
    WeightedAverageIfs = 0
    Else
    WeightedAverageIfs = per1
    End If
End Function
```

I hope this will help people out in the future. For anyone not familiar with excel and VBA you will need to open the developer console. Insert a new module and paste one of the code segments above. After doing that you can simply type the function with arguments =WeightedAverageIf("Range of your data","What you need to match in the range","What column in the range is the searched data in", "Column with the weighting of the averaged numbers", "Column with the averaged numbers")